# I need help creating a loop in dev console in firefox

Tags: javascript, loops

I am trying to use the dev console to give mario a mushroom every 5 seconds (in the browser game super mario html5)

I can give mario mushrooms manually by typing marioShroons(mario) but I would like to have it on loop so I don't have to pause the game every time I want a mushroom. I have tried a while loop and set timeout but I can't figure it out. The only coding languages I familiar with are c++ and html.
**

```
while(data.time.amount > 0) {
  killOtherCharacters()
}

setTimeout(function() {
  killOtherCharacters()
}, 1000);
```

I expected these lines of code to not give me a mushroom, but to automatically kill enemies. But on the first try (the while loop) it froze the tab and I had to reload the page.

With the set timeout, it didn't make any obvious results, it killed all near characters once and then stopped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You tried using `setTimeout`, and it only worked once. This is to be expected, because:

> `Window.setTimeout()` sets a timer which executes a function or specified piece of code once the timer expires

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout)

What you need to do is use `setInterval`:

> The `setInterval()` method...repeatedly calls a function or executes a code snippet, with a fixed time delay between each call.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/enUS/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval)

So in your console, you should write this:

```
setInterval(killOtherCharacters, 1000);
```

(I removed the anonymous function because it wasn't needed - you only need an anonymous function if you're passing parameters or doing multiple things. You do need to remove the `()` for this though).

And if you want to stop the function from executing, assign a variable to the interval:

```
var killCharacters = setInterval(killOtherCharacters, 1000);
```

Then call `clearInterval` upon this variable to clear the interval (stop the loop):

```
clearInterval(killCharacters);
```

Comment: how do I make a loop but to give mario a mushroom

Comment: @Tnings How can you give Mario a mushroom? Is there a function like `giveMarioMushroom()`? Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your while loop froze the page is because Javascript can only do one thing at a time and you told it to always run your while function, blocking all other Javascript from running on your site.

setTimeout is only run once after a set time ([see documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout)), if you want to run something every x miliseconds it's better to [use setInterval instead](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval).

```
var intervalID = window.setInterval(killOtherCharacters(), 500); //run this every 500 ms
```

Answer (score 0):

Use setInterval if you want killOtherCharacters() to be called repeatedly.

```
const interval = setInterval(function() {killOtherCharacters() },1000);
```

Then when you want the function to stop being called:

```
clearInterval(interval);
```